# Selecting all rows before a given time in SQL

Tags: mysql, datetime, select, mysql-workbench

I have a fairly simple SQL table (using MYSQL Workbench 8.0) where the rows of the table contain dates and values like so:

```
        date         |   value
 --------------------|----------
 2018-09-06 18:00:00 |    73
```

Values in the date column range from %18:00:00 to %17:30:00.
All I would like to do is return results from a query where I exclude all rows where the time in the date column is before 17:00:00.
The query I am currently using to no avail is:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name where td_time <> '%17%'
```

For reference, the values in column 'date' are formatted as type datetime.

I believe I'm missing something fairly simple, but this is my 2nd day using SQL and I cannot figure out if I am missing a small nuance to the syntax.

Comment: You need to use `NOT LIKE '%17%'` rather than `<> '%17%'`

Comment: Have you looked at the [TIME()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_time) function?

Comment: @Nick, this did exactly what I needed. Thank you for pointing out the quick fix

Comment: @jod51 you should note that it will also exclude a time such as `14:17:00` or `09:04:17`. You might want to be more specific and use `NOT LIKE '%17:%:' to avoid that, or if `td_time` is a time string, just use `HOUR(td_time) != 17`

Comment: How many rows are we talking about.  Performance wise, we're having to extract the hour; which means no indexes.

Comment: @Nick, ah that makes sense. I went with NOT LIKE '%17:%mm:%ss' and that seems to properly include times such as 14:17:00 or 09:04:17

Answer (score 0):

There are many function in MySQL to process time and date value, you can do like this:

```
select * from table where hour(date) < 17 and hour(date) > 17
```

Or

```
select * from table where time(date) < '17:00:00' and time(date) > '18:00:00'
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me because it is too broad; it returns all dates with the time before 17:00:00 but removes times after 17:59:00 which I still need. I am essentially trying to exclude the hour between 17:00:00 - 18:00:00

Comment: Why not `WHERE hour(Date) <> 17` or `WHERE EXTRACT(HOUR FROM date) <> 17`;